# Unable to create SVG Groups

Tags: d3.js

Using d3.js, I'm trying to create a series of SVG groups (i.e. `<g>` elements), with a `<g>` element for each number in an array of data. Each `<g>` element should itself contain a `<rect>` and a `<text>`. The following code looks to me like it should do that, but when I inspect the `<svg>` element (in both Chrome and Firefox), it contains `<rect>` elements and `<text>` elements directly inside the `<svg>` element, with no `<g>` elements in sight.

The HTML page initially contains just an empty `<svg>` element. `dataset` is just a simple array of numbers.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .call( function(g) {
        g.append("rect")
            .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i))
            .attr("y", d => h - yScale(d))
            .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr("height", d => yScale(d))
            .attr("fill", d => "rgb(0,0," + (d*10) + ")")
            .on('click', d => console.log(d))
            .on('mouseover', function() {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr('fill', 'orange');
                })
            .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                    .duration(250)
                    .attr("fill", d => "rgb(0,0," + (d*10) + ")")
                });
        })
    .call( function(g) {
        g.append('text')
            .text(d => d)
            .attr('class','label')
            .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2)
            .attr("y", d =>  h - yScale(d) + 14);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. I thought that `selectAll('g').data(dataset).enter()` would result in the `<g>` elements that don't match up with data in `dataset` being created for me. But they're not, and it's necessary to add `.append('g')` after the call to `.enter()` to actually create the missing `<g>` elements. After that, the function called by `.call(...)` will be passed the new `<g>` element.